# Как считать данные которые относятся к одной категории?

Tags: php, api, rest

У меня есть простое api которое я делал по данному принципу https://only-to-top.ru/blog/programming/2019-11-06-rest-api-php.html
Мне нужно считать данные которые относятся к одной из категорий, для этого я добавил в таблице строку с названием category_id, в которой указываю к какой категории относится товар.

Есть модель товара в которой идет функция считывания всех товаров

```
function read() {

    // выбираем все записи
    $query = "SELECT
                c.name as category_name, f.id, f.name, f.url, f.status, f.category_id, f.created
            FROM
                " . $this->table_name . " f
                LEFT JOIN
                    categories c
                        ON f.category_id = c.id
            ORDER BY
                f.created DESC";

    // подготовка запроса
    $stmt = $this->conn->prepare($query);

    // выполняем запрос
    $stmt->execute();

    return $stmt;
}
```

И само считывание по адресу site.ru/api/read.php

```
<?php
// необходимые HTTP-заголовки
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
header("Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET");

// подключение базы данных и файл, содержащий объекты
include_once "../config/database.php";
include_once "../models/faucet.php";

// получаем соединение с базой данных
$database = new Database();
$db = $database->getConnection();

// инициализируем объект
$faucet = new Faucet($db);
 
// запрашиваем товары
$stmt = $faucet->read();
$num = $stmt->rowCount();

// проверка, найдено ли больше 0 записей
if ($num>0) {

    // массив товаров
    $faucet_arr = array();
    $faucet_arr["records"] = array();

    // получаем содержимое нашей таблицы
    // fetch() быстрее, чем fetchAll()
    while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {

        // извлекаем строку
        extract($row);

        $faucet_item = array(
            "id" => $id,
            "name" => $name,
            "url" => $url,
            "status" => $status,
            "category_id" => $category_id,
            "category_name" => $category_name
        );

        array_push($faucet_arr["records"], $faucet_item);
    }

    // устанавливаем код ответа - 200 OK
    http_response_code(200);

    // выводим данные о товаре в формате JSON
    echo json_encode($faucet_arr);
} else {

    // установим код ответа - 404 Не найдено
    http_response_code(404);

    // сообщаем пользователю, что товары не найдены
    echo json_encode(array("message" => "Faucet list not found."), JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);
}
```

Добавил в read.php

```
// установим свойство ID записи для чтения
$faucet->category_id = isset($_GET["category_id"]) ? $_GET["category_id"] : die();
```

А функцию изменил на

```
 // выбираем все записи
    $query = "SELECT
                c.name as category_name, f.id, f.name, f.url, f.status, f.category_id, f.created
            FROM
                " . $this->table_name . " f
                LEFT JOIN
                    categories c
                        ON f.category_id = c.id
            ORDER BY
                f.id";

    // подготовка запроса
    $stmt = $this->conn->prepare($query);

    // выполняем запрос
    $stmt->execute();

    return $stmt;
```

Comment: и в чем загвоздка то? добавьте get-параметр с ID категории и фильтройте по нему запрос. зы: этот волшебный while с extract можно заменить на худой конец на `$result[] = $row`,  а вообще есть `fetchAll`

Comment: Если я ввожу так /read.php?category_id=1 все равно показывает все записи

Comment: само собой то оно не заработет, очевидно ведь? добавить надо `$catId = $_GET['category_id]`, заменить вообще `left join` на `inner`, добавить туда условие `про этот ID`. главное добавлять его только в том случае, когда параметр таки пришел

Comment: Добавил в read.php // установим свойство ID записи для чтения
$faucet->category_id = isset($_GET["category_id"]) ? $_GET["category_id"] : die();

Comment: А сама функция  // выбираем все записи
    $query = "SELECT
                c.name as category_name, f.id, f.name, f.url, f.status, f.category_id, f.created
            FROM
                " . $this->table_name . " f
                LEFT JOIN
                    categories c
                        ON f.category_id = c.id
            ORDER BY
                f.id";

    // подготовка запроса
    $stmt = $this->conn->prepare($query);

    // выполняем запрос
    $stmt->execute();

    return $stmt;

Comment: и где этот sql запрос учитывает эту `$this->categoryId` ?

Comment: Помогите составить я в этом мало что понимаю